# Arrays of Hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am in my last week of pre work before my live classes start next week and I am hung up on this one problem and I was hoping someone could tell me where I'm going wrong.

This is the what they want us to do:
Create a new array of hashes called great_movies which only contains movies with a rating greater than 3 and where each hash contains only the title and boxart information. The program should end with: p great_movies.

This is the code we are given:

```
    movies = [
      {
        "id" => 70111470,
        "title" => "Die Hard",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 5.0,
        "bookmark" => []
      },
      {
        "id" => 654356453,
        "title" => "Bad Boys",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 2.0,
        "bookmark" => [{ "id" => 432534, "time" => 65876586 }]
      },
      {
        "id" => 65432445,
        "title" => "The Chamber",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 4.0,
        "bookmark" => []
      },
      {
        "id" => 675465,
        "title" => "Fracture",
        "boxart" => "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture.jpg",
        "uri" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
        "rating" => 3.0,
        "bookmark" => [{ "id" => 432534, "time" => 65876586 }]
      }
    ]
```

This is what I have come up with so far but I don't think I am going about it the right way?
class Movies

```
  def initialize(id, title, boxart, url, rating, bookmark)
    @id = id
    @title = title
    @boxart = boxart
    @url = url
    @rating = rating
    @bookmark = bookmark
  end

  def id
    @id
  end

  def title
    @title
  end

  def boxart
    @boxart
  end

  def url
    @url
  end

  def rating
    @rating
  end

  def bookmark
    @bookmark
  end
end
```

Then I put in all of the information the way they showed us how to but for some reason it wouldn't let me post that here I just did four different instances of Movies.new and put all of the information into those.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated and just as a side note we just recently learned about the whole class method thing that's why I tried to do it that way because at least in my mind with that being the most recent thing they showed us that it what I was trying to use.

Comment: You show a class definition, but you don't show any usage of this class. Also, it's not clear to me _why_ you create this class. Are you thinking of practicing data modelling on a larger perspective? In this case, the class may make sense and you would first transform the array of hashes into an array of `Movies` objects, and add a method i.e. `great_movie?` to this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating a whole new class is rather overkill.  You simply need to understand the methods already available for an array.

I am not going to provide you a direct solution as this is homework and SO isn't here to do your homework for you.  But let's consider an array:

```rb
foo = [1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 5]
```

I can get values larger than `3` by using the `select` method and giving it an appropriate block.

```rb
greater_than_3 = foo.select { |x| x > 3 }
```

Now `greater_than_3` is `[4, 8, 5]`.

What if I want an array containing each of those values, multiplied by two? I can can use the `map` method and another block.

```rb
greater_than_3 = foo.select { |x| x > 3 }
times_two = greater_than_3.map { |x| x * 2 }
```

Now `times_two` is `[8, 16, 10]`.

As this is homework, I'll leave you to see how you can apply these methods to solve your problem, rather than directly giving you an answer you can copy and paste.

Documentation for the Ruby [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html) mixin which provides the [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html) class with these methods should help you on your way.

Comment: ok thank you I kinda thought that I was going the wrong direction setting up that class but I couldn't think of any other way to do it I'm going to apply what you put in the comment there and see if that will get me where I need to go.

Comment: Your answer would be more comparable to the question if you had mulitple criteria for `select`, such as `x > 3` and `x` even. Note that Ruby 3.0 provides a method that combines `select` and `map`: [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) (though `map` is unrelated to the question).

Comment: GIven the data provided, I interpreted the question as asking to select movies with a rating higher than 3, and then only provide the title and boxart info for them. As it stands, interpreting it the way you have would yield no results. I can see the assignment being slightly ambiguous that way, though.

Comment: Good luck, @Philip Jobe. I hope the answer helps.

Comment: @Chris, yes, I misread the question. Philip, to restrict a hash to only certain keys see [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).